# How to programmatically check the android upper SMS message size

Tags: android

I am creating an android application to check the SMS limit size on the device running the application, programmatically. I searched a lot but couldn't find anything. I'm thinking about getting the device features and properties to check the SMS limit size but don't know whether it is possible or not.

Please help me find out how to solve this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: SMS not limit size in android.

Comment: What is it exactly that you want to check? The character limit for a single-part message? Or the maximum size for a multipart message?

Answer (score 0):

The limit is **160** 7-bit characters. So if your message contains only latin chars, it is limited to 160 chars. However, if it contains something Arabic or Chinese, the limit might be as low as 70 chars since they are encoded in 16-bits.

Comment: I want to check it programmatically in android.

Comment: What do you want to check? I don't think it is something that you can retrieve from Android device info/properties.

Comment: Is it a constant in all android devices that the limit is 160 or 70, or no it is variable.